# Using fail2ban to scan for SSH Accepted Connections and write the username to auth.log

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, log-files, fail2ban

I have a small server that authenticate users as root using their ssh-keys stored in authorized_keys file. I also run fail2ban.

I made a convention to have a nickname written after the public_key of each user in the authorized_keys file.

I would like to know if it would be possible to have fail2ban to scan for accepted connections and, instead of jailing the user, to write a line with his nickname to /var/log/auth.log, perhaps using logger -p auth.info "*Timestamp* Accepted SSH connection from *nickname*"

Cheers

Comment: This might require more details on what you have already tried, including your configuration and example of the logging.

Answer (score 0):

However I don't know why you need it, where sshd already writes real user name in the form like:

```
Accepted publickey for username from IP ...
```

If you don't have it, may be you can try to set sshd_config' loglevel to VERBOSE.

But back to fail2ban, sure it is possible.
As for jail you'd need to specify something like this (along with others):

```ini
[ssh-accept-mon]
failregex = ^\s*\S+ sshd\[\d+\]: Accepted publickey for <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> from <ADDR>
maxretry = 1
findtime = 1
bantime = 1
enabled = true
action = ssh-accept-mon-log
```

Here how you can check the RE and captured groups:

```bash
$ what='Jul 12 19:50:00 srv sshd[274594]: Accepted publickey for admin from 192.0.2.5 port 59120 ssh2: ECDSA-CERT:...'
$ fail2ban-regex -o '<F-USER> : <ip>' "$what" '^\s*\S+ sshd\[\d+\]: Accepted publickey for <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> from <HOST>'
admin : 192.0.2.5
```

As an action you need to use something like this:

```ini
[Definition]
actionban = logger -p auth.info "<time> Accepted SSH connection from <F-USER>"
```

Just note that it would not log more than 1 entry per IP per second (due to `bantime`), so may be you'd try some solution from [fail2ban :: wiki :: How to ban something other than host (IP-address), like user or mail, etc](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-ban-something-other-as-host-(IP-address),-like-user-or-mail,-etc.).

For instance RE from this example will use "session-ID" (matched with `<F-ID>\d+</F-ID>`) as a failure ID instead of IP address, so would "ban" by this ID (and therefore safe against too fast entries):

```bash
$ fail2ban-regex -o '<F-USER> : <fid> : <ip>' "$what" '^\s*\S+ sshd\[<F-ID>\d+</F-ID>\]: Accepted publickey for <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> from <ADDR>'
admin : 274594 : 192.0.2.5
```

Also consider [this RFE - fail2ban#2304](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2304) for alternate approach (or alternative with `ignorecommand` etc).